# Select the same elements from lists

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I need a special intersectant operation for **List** other than **Set**.

There maybe some duplicate elements, also need to count instead of merging as `Intersection`.

For example:

$a=\{1,{\color\red{2}},2,{\color\red{3}},{\color\red{3}},3,4,4,4\}$

$b=\{{\color\red{2}},{\color\red{3}},{\color\red{3}},5\}$

$c=\{{\color\red{2}},2,{\color\red{3}},{\color\red{3}},4,4\}$

One 2 and two 3 appear in all list.

So $a\sqcap b\sqcap c=\{2,3,3\}$.

---

**My rough attemption:**

```
ListIntersection[list__]:=Module[{tlist=Tally/@{list},elements},
  elements=First/@Intersection[Sequence@@tlist,SameTest->(First[#1]==First[#2]&)];
  take[a_,b_]:=a[[Sequence@@(FirstPosition[a,b]+{0,1})]];
  min[b_]:=Min[take[#,b]&/@tlist];
  Flatten[ConstantArray@@@Transpose[{elements,min/@elements}]]
]
```

Test set:

```
a={1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4};
b={2,3,3,5};
c={2,2,3,3,4,4};
ListIntersection[a,b,c]
```

Answer:

```
{2, 3, 3}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe my approach is fairly similar to yours, but uses [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)'s and some built in operations on them to make the code somewhat simpler.  (The fact that several of these functions have operator forms makes the code especially clean.)

```
ClearAll[multiIntersection]
multiIntersection[lists__List] := (
  Counts /@ {lists}
       // KeyIntersection
      // Merge[Min]
     // KeySort
    // KeyValueMap[ConstantArray]
   // Catenate
  )
```

You can remove the `KeySort` if you don't want the returned elements to be sorted.

```
multiIntersection[a, b, c]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 3}
> ```

---

**Edit:**  Eliminated the needlessly cumbersome `ConstantArray[#1, #2] &` in favor of `ConstantArray`.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `Intersection` directly if we label each list value with a number indicating how many times that value has occurred in the list so far:

```
label[list_] := Module[{n}, n[_] = 0; #[++n[#]]& /@ list]

label[a]
(* {1[1], 2[1], 2[2], 3[1], 3[2], 3[3], 4[1], 4[2], 4[3]} *)
```

So then:

```
(Intersection@@(label /@ {a, b, c}))[[All, 0]]
(* {2, 3, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Catenate[Table@@@Normal[Merge[KeyIntersection[Counts/@{a,b,c}],Min]]]
```

> `{2, 3, 3}`

Answer (score 1):

```
ListIntersection[list__] := Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray,
   {#, MapThread[Min, Outer[Count, {list}, #, 1]]} &[Intersection[list]]]

ListIntersection[a, b, c]
```

> `{2, 3, 3}`

Comment: Hello, the result is `{2, 3, 3}`. :)

Comment: @yode Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1):

A simple looping method.

```
a = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4};
b = {2, 3, 3, 5};
c = {2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4};

SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]

f[l_, d_, il_] := If[il, If[++l > Length[d], Throw[x]]]

i = j = k = 1;
x = {};

Catch[While[True,
  If[a[[i]] == b[[j]] == c[[k]],
   AppendTo[x, a[[i]]];
   ii = ij = ik = True,
   ii = a[[i]] < b[[j]] || a[[i]] < c[[k]];
   ij = b[[j]] < a[[i]] || b[[j]] < c[[k]];
   ik = c[[k]] < a[[i]] || c[[k]] < b[[j]]];
  f[i, a, ii];
  f[j, b, ij];
  f[k, c, ik];
  ]]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 3}
> ```